# Pretty print for all classes with ranged-base for loop support

Tags: c++

I want to implement pretty-print for all classes with ranged-base for loop support by overloadding <<. The (wrong) code is like this.

```
template<class C> ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const C& v) {
  for(auto x : v) out<<x<<' ';
  return out;
}
```

The problem here is that this will conflict with existing << overloading. Is there a way to specify in the template that C must support ranged-base for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since range-based for loops require `begin(v)` and `end(v)` to be valid with ADL (and `std::` being an associated namespace), you can use this:

```
namespace support_begin_end
{
    // we use a special namespace (above) to
    // contain the using directive for 'std':
    using namespace std;

    // the second parameter is only valid
    // when begin(C()) and end(C()) are valid
    template<typename C,
        typename=decltype(begin(std::declval<C>()),end(std::declval<C>()))
    >
    struct impl
    {
        using type = void; // only here impl
    };

    // explicitly disable conflicting types here
    template<>
    struct impl<std::string>;
}

// this uses the above to check for ::type,
// which only exists if begin/end are valid
// and there is no specialization to disable it
// (like in the std::string case)
template<class C,typename = typename supports_begin_end::impl<C>::type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const C& v) {
    for(auto x : v) out<<x<<' ';
    return out;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/663175e47c9a70aa)

There are other types that are suitable for range-based loops, though. Don't know if you need to detect them as well.

---

Here's an updated [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f505bf41c6dd5beb) which detects both containers/types that support `begin(v)`/`end(v)` as well as types that support `v.begin()`/`v.end()`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little bit of what's happening here? Would be lovely thanks!

Answer (score 6):

SFINAE:

```
template<class C>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const C& v) -> decltype(v.begin(), v.end(), (out))
//                                          or -> decltype(std::begin(v), std::end(v), (out))
{
    for (auto x : v)
        out << x << ' ';
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A general comment on all the answers:

Using

```
for (auto x : v)
```

will COPY all the elements out of the collection before printing them, resulting in a lot of calls to the copy constructor and destructor.  You're probably better off with

```
for (auto &x : v)
```

as your loop.